# How to add a Quote to the title page of a beamer representation?

Tags: beamer

I am using the LaTeX document class beamer to prepare presentation, and I want to add a famous quote at the title page, specifically at the low right corner, How could I do that ?
see the descriptive image.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Currently, your question is a bit vague and leaves room for interpretation and some details unaddresses, such as the following: Which beamer theme do you use? Where exactly on the titlepage would you like to place the quote? Please prepara a sketch fo the expected output as well as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your current titlepage.

Answer (score 2):

For beamer v3.70 or newer, you could add the quote to the `date` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\author{Author}
\title{Title}

\addtobeamertemplate{date}{}{\par\scriptsize\vskip1cm\hfill\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright some quote to be shown here\par \raggedleft Famous person}}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it what You need?
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\vspace{7cm}
\epigraph{quote quote quote quote quote quote}{Author}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```